# HMS Nearby Service-Why does the BeaconManager app report status code 502 or 401?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

The BeaconManager demo app keeps reporting status code 401 upon beacon registration. The document indicates that authentication has expired, but a local JSON file is used in this case. Why can't beacons be registered for the demo app that uses Nearby Message to receive messages.

$$$ Device: HUAWEI Mate 10 (ALP-AL00) Android10 EMUI10.0.0

$$$ Log: BeaconBase_BeaconDiscover: Failed, code:502, info:Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BeaconManger demo app helps you learn how to integrate HUAWEI Nearby Service better. When using the demo app, pay attention to the following:

1. Follow instructions in our documentation to apply for a service account key and download the corresponding JSON file. Do not generate a JWT by yourself.
2. Ensure that the data storage location is the same as the location where beacons are registered.
3. When setting MESSAGE_HOST on the demo app, ensure that the setting is consistent with the data storage location specified in our documentation.